# PyCharm very slow even for simple commands repeated several times

Tags: pycharm

My PyCharm is very slow: the 'python console' requires seconds to print a line or compute sqrt(2), even after I repeated the operations several times (I was told the first run of a command might be slower). Do you have any idea of the reason ? mac OS 10.11.6 + python 3.5 and 3.7 + PyCharm 2018.3 community edition

I opened a question few days ago about problems with graphical outputs in PyCharm ([PyCharm doesn’t display plots and is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53669034/pycharm-doesn-t-display-plots-and-is-very-slow), that is not solved by the way), where I considered this slowness could be connected, but since I'm not sure, I reopen a new post specific to this slowness problem.

I know this is out topic for stackoverflow to compare tools, but this is the second time in few days I have troubles with PyCharm that I don't have with spyder...

Comment: What hardware do you use? what is your system configuration?

Comment: sorry, my post was incomplet

Answer (score 0):

Actually thats just the way that PyCharm and a lot of InteliJ products behave. They are far from being a sleek, lighweight IDE. On the other side they are loaded with amazing features. It's the best to run them on machines with 8 gigs of RAM, and a decent CPU.

Comment: I have a RAM:16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 and CPU: 2,5 GHz Intel Core i7 (4 cores). It seems to me if PyCharm can not have a decent speed with this, it is not an acceptable tool. But it also seems to me it is more likely there's something I do wrong...

Comment: well then it is definitly wrong, but it would be hard to detect what slows him down. Maybe write to pycharm support?